# Getting vm aborting error with android web view

Tags: android, webview, fatal-error

I made a webview activity which will crash after loading webpage(sometimes show unfortunately stopeed somtime show nothing just closed the app).

Here is my code and logcat. Please help.

Logcat:

```
04-02 11:43:27.708: E/dalvikvm(32517): VM aborting
04-02 11:43:27.709: A/libc(32517): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 32546 (WebViewCoreThre)
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mywebview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText field;
    private WebView browser;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    }

    public void open(View view) {

        url = field.getText().toString();

        if (url.startsWith("http://")) {

        } else {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }

        browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        browser.loadUrl(url);


    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/urlField"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:ems="10" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/urlField"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:onClick="open"
      android:text="@string/browse" />

   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not correct. Please remove the call to `loadUrl` from it and have this function return `false`.

There's no need to load the URL again from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. The load is already in progress.